# Kotlin nested Recyclerview

Tags: kotlin, android-recyclerview

I really appropriate it if somebody could help me out.

I apply my second RecyclerView with a custom swipe Button object, here *fun handleSwipeClick* is set to handle the action.

My question is: how can i make this function (*handleSwipeClick*) to handle each row specifically?? Like Delete this row item

Adapter #1

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val item = baxters[position]
        holder.listItem_time.text = item.intakeTime

        holder.itemView.dose_recycler_view.apply {
            dose_recycler_view.setHasFixedSize(true)
            layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
            dose_recycler_view.layoutManager = layoutManager

            //Swipe action
            val swipe = object: SwipeHelper(context,dose_recycler_view, 400){
                override fun instaniateSwipeButton(
                    viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder,
                    buffer: MutableList<SwipeButton>
                ) {
                    // Adding Buttons
                    buffer.add(
                        SwipeButton(context,
                            "",
                            30,
                            R.drawable.ic_check_circle,
                            Color.parseColor("#66ff66"),
                            object : ButtonClickListener {
                                override fun handleSwipeClick(id: Int) {
                                    // Click action
                                    // TODO call to change LAST TAKEN and NEW INTAKE
                                    Companion.errorToast(
                                        context,
                                        "Medicijn ingenomen. $id"
                                    )
                                }
                            })
                    )
                }

            }

            adapter = ClientDoseListAdapter(item.doses.toMutableList())
            setRecycledViewPool(viewPool)
        }
    }
```

Adapter #2

```
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val item = doses[position]

/// DELETE THIS ROW
        holder.med_name.text = item.medicineItem.name
        holder.dose_amount.text = item.amount.toString()
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First, create a delete method in ClientDoseListAdapter adapter, then call this method in the click action like,

```
fun delete(dose: Dose) {
        val index: Int = doseList.indexOf(dose)
        doseList.removeAt(index)
        notifyDataSetChanged()
}

override fun handleSwipeClick(id: Int) { 
    // Click action 
    adapter.delete(adapter.getItem(viewHolder.adapterPosition)) 
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much sir, i could not call delete method directly from adapte.delete(). but i solved that by initializing a ClientDoseAdapter.

Answer (score 0):

Adapetr #1 looks like this:

```
 override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val item = baxters[position]
        holder.listItem_time.text = item.intakeTime

        holder.itemView.dose_recycler_view.apply {
            dose_recycler_view.setHasFixedSize(true)
            layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
            dose_recycler_view.layoutManager = layoutManager

            // First init a new adapter
            dosesAdapter = ClientDoseListAdapter(item.doses.toMutableList())


            // Swipe action
            val swipe = object: SwipeHelper(context, dose_recycler_view, 400){
                override fun instaniateSwipeButton(
                    viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder,
                    buffer: MutableList<SwipeButton>
                ) {
                    // Adding Buttons
                    buffer.add(
                        SwipeButton(context,
                            "",
                            30,
                            R.drawable.ic_check_circle,
                            Color.parseColor("#66ff66"),
                            object : ButtonClickListener {
                                override fun confirmDoseTaken(id: Int) {
                                    // Click action
                                    // TODO call to change LAST TAKEN and NEW INTAKE
                                    Companion.errorToast(
                                        context,
                                        "Medicijn ingenomen. $id"
                                    )

                                    // i can call removeItem method in adapter
                                    dosesAdapter.removeItem()
                                }
                            })
                    )
                }

            }

            // set recyclerView adapter
            adapter = dosesAdapter
            setRecycledViewPool(viewPool)
        }
    }
```